# What is wrong with this jquery syntax

Tags: jquery

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with this jquery syntax?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.toggle-nav') || $('#navigation li a').click(function(){
        $('#navigation').toggle();
    }
}); 
});
```

Comment: "*Whats wrong*" depends entirely on what you wanted it to do, what its doing instead and what it's not doing. Are there any errors?

Comment: You are not binding the click event to a jQuery object. The `if` statement does not return a jQuey object, too. You should describe what you're trying to achieve, instead of posting a piece of code, sans context, and asking it to be explained and dissected.

Comment: the error i got says: Line 5: Expected ')' and instead saw '}' i dont understand what it is.

Comment: I have a class 'toggle-nav' and some 'li' items in a menu i want if either is clicked it toggles the entire menu.the script worked without the "|| $('navigation li a') section i recently added that part to get some additional functionality and got the error. i am just learning jquery so some things i don't know yet.

Comment: Wherr is the releated HTML? What is the purpose of the script?

Comment: <div id="navigation"><ul class="active">
                          <li><a href="#tab-1">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#tab-2">Services</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#tab-3">Products</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#tab-4">Contact</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#tab-5">About</a></li>   
                    </ul>

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running your JavaScript through a linter like [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [jshint](http://jshint.com/) in order to detect syntax, formatting, and other common JavaScript errors.  It should tell you the problem with your code.